# Repeated 2-layer css parallax background in Firefox with css "transform" and "perspective" (background not cut off at content height)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

You are my last hope.
I decided to implement an update to the Page of my brothers store. One of the new features I wanted was a (simple^^) parallax background with two layers to create a kind of 3d-feeling while scrolling.

First I got it to work with a little bit of JS, adjusting the position on scroll events with a multiplicator. Then I noticed that the performance of the background is sticky, laggy, stuttering and doesn't really look well in Firefox. As far I could see this was because of the "Asynchronous Panning"-Feature of the browser.

[Link to the JS-Version of the page update](https://hzkb.de/versuch%20website/start.html)

So after a little time with the search engine of my choice I saw no option to disable or work around that feature and decided to start working on a CSS-only implementation on that site.

And guess which browser is not able to display everything as wanted? Firefox!

First I stuffed all my content into divs, so that - so my hope - a mutual parent div would enable me to use "height: 100%;"  to scale the div's together. That didn't work as the the background was overflowing over my content. The problem was: Because I wanted the background images to repeat on the y-axis AND to move with a slower speed as the content I had to define a specific height of the background divs which is larger than the content height.

I even tried to set the height of the background divs with jQuery by

```
$(#background).height($(.main_content_container).height());
```

but the background always just turned out to be too large or too short.

After my idea with the parent div didn't work I started to work with the body and my content container itself to generate perspective. Could this have worked when i would've set all height to 100%? When I set height: 100%; I always got my viewport's height...

What I got now:

Creating the perspective and applying transform with body causing the overflow-y:

```
    body {
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      perspective: 1px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100vh;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      align-items: center;
      align-content: center;
      align-self: center;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    #background {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
      width: 100vw;
      background-size: 100vw;
      background-image: url(websiteimage.png);
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 500vh;
      min-width: 100vw;
    }
    #background2 {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateZ(-3px) scale(4);
      background-image: url(websiteimage2.png);
      background-size: 100vw;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 500vh;
      min-width: 100vw;
      opacity: 80%;
    }
div.main_content_container {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: Silver;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 100%;
  }
```

[In-vivo page (only startpage and only in dark mode is "working" at the moment)](https://hzkb.de/cssversuch/start.html)

Why does Chrome cut off the bottom of the background divs just as wanted and Firefox just create visible overflow?
Is there any chance to get one of my solutions to work fluent and formatted in Firefox?

I'm puzzling around for days now and thankful for every kind of idea/suggestion.

PS: This is my first post on StackOverflow. I hope I provided enough info and didn't break any rules as this site often helped me out of the hell of amateur webdesign.

PPS: I know my code is kind of a mess after all that puzzling but I'm playing around for days now

Answer (score 0):

For all having the same problem:

I decided to try out several tweaks on my JS-implementation again and reached an improvement by adding

```
position: fixed;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: top;
```

to the background layers.

I also added a script by keith clark but I'm not sure if it takes any effect:

```
/*
Firefox super responsive scroll (c) Keith Clark - MIT Licensed
*/
(function(doc) {
console.log("Document executed")
  var root = doc.documentElement,
      scrollbarWidth, scrollEvent;

  // Not ideal, but better than UA sniffing.
  if ("MozAppearance" in root.style) {

    // determine the vertical scrollbar width
    scrollbarWidth = root.clientWidth;
    root.style.overflow = "scroll";
    scrollbarWidth -= root.clientWidth;
    root.style.overflow = "";

    // create a synthetic scroll event
    scrollEvent = doc.createEvent("UIEvent")
    scrollEvent.initEvent("scroll", true, true);

    // event dispatcher
    function scrollHandler() {
      doc.dispatchEvent(scrollEvent)
    }

    // detect mouse events in the document scrollbar track
    doc.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      if (e.clientX > root.clientWidth - scrollbarWidth) {
        doc.addEventListener("mousemove", scrollHandler, false);
        doc.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
          doc.removeEventListener("mouseup", arguments.callee, false);
          doc.removeEventListener("mousemove", scrollHandler, false);
        }, false)
      }
    }, false)

    // override mouse wheel behaviour.
    doc.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
      // Don't disable hot key behaviours
      if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey) {
        root.scrollTop += e.detail * 16;
        scrollHandler.call(this, e);
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    }, false)

  }
})(document);
```

Still no improvement on iOS Safari and mobile Firefox afaics.

Edit:
Thats the jQuery-function causing the effect here:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#background').css('background-position-y', $(window).scrollTop() * -.15);
  });
});  
$(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#background2').css('background-position-y', $(window).scrollTop() * -.09);
  });
  });
```